# What is the deprecation policy for Flash/Flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

Does Adobe ever mark stuff as deprecated? If so, does it eventually get removed or does the old stuff live forever?

Comment: Do you mean within the Flex framework or within Flash?

Comment: They have 'discontinued' the development of some components in the `Spark` architecture. e.g. `Repeater` is an `mx` component of which no `Spark` equivalent will ever be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen Adobe remove functionality from AS3/Flash Player, as this would break backwards compatibility. Sure, AS3 is not compatible at all with AS2, but other than that, things should be stable.

Flex, on the other hand, does have things change from time to time and Adobe has, in the past, often deprecated certain classes and methods. Every major release of Flex usually changes things a lot, but they do try to provide backwards compatibility so that a Flex 3 application (for example) could compile in Flex 4, though there's no guarantee of this.

**TL;DR**: Within Flash Player, don't worry about it. With the Flex framework, be advised— try to stay up to date with the framework.

Answer (score 2):

A small example I can give is `random()` is non-existent since AS3.

```
AS2: trace( random(5) ); // 2
AS3: trace( random(5) ); // 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method random.
```